# How to fix "thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value" while using "ZoKrates" in docker?

Tags: docker, ethereum, ubuntu-18.04

I am using "`ZoKrates"(0.4.6) toolbox in "docker"(18.09.2) at Ubuntu 18.04` , while compiling a code I got the following :

```
zokrates@ff141f88fb6d:~$ ./zokrates compile -i test.code
```

Compiling test.code

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
>   value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or
>   directory" }', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5

note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the wrong folder. Make sure that you do exactly this:

```
docker run -v <path to your project folder>:/home/zokrates/code -ti zokrates/zokrates /bin/bash
```

Replace  by dragging the folder of zokrates onto terminal. Then use ls to see the files you have. Use cd to change into the folder where you have your code file. Once inside, perform:

```
~/zokrates compile -I <enter the .code file here>
```